# How to pass button value to another module? Promise evaluation error

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I want to pass button value to `mod_test_server` and display it in `mod_test_server` using `renderPrint`. Don't know why I can pass its value only once. Next clicks cause no action - no value passing. What I can see in console is this strange error:

> Warning in 'renderPrint(...)': restarting interrupted promise evaluation

I was searching for a solution, I think it has something to do with promises but I've never come across such a problem and use a lot of reactivity. Why it happens? And how to make it work?

Here's the reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)


moduleServer <- function(id, module) {
   callModule(module, id)
}

# UI - btn #
mod_btn_UI <- function(id) {
   ns <- NS(id)
   
   actionBttn(ns("btn"), "Click me")
}

# Server - btn #
mod_btn_server <- function(id){
   moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
      
      return(reactive({input$btn}))
   })
}

# UI - table #
mod_test_UI <- function(id) {
   ns <- NS(id)
   
   verbatimTextOutput(ns("myBtn"))
}

# Server - table #
mod_test_server <- function(id, btn){
   moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns

      output$myBtn <- renderPrint({btn})
   })
}


# App #
ui <- fluidPage(
   
   tagList(
      mod_btn_UI("btn"),
      mod_test_UI("test")
   )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   
   button <- mod_btn_server("btn")
   btnClicked <- eventReactive(button(),{
                                button()})
   
   mod_test_server("test", btnClicked())   

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`btn` is reactive in `mod_test_server` module. Try this

```
# Server - table #
mod_test_server <- function(id, btn){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
    
    output$myBtn <- renderPrint({btn()})
  })
}


# App #
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tagList(
    mod_btn_UI("btn"),
    mod_test_UI("test")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  button <- mod_btn_server("btn")
  btnClicked <- eventReactive(button,{
    button})
  
  mod_test_server("test", btnClicked() )   
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Also, check how `button` is used in `eventReactive`.